# Constant Alert for Audio playing on marker detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, aframe, ar.js

I have a site with A-frame and AR.JS where I have audio playing upon marker detection. However, when the marker is in view, I get this alert constantly popping up several times in console.

```
'components audio warn All the sounds are playing. If you need to play more sounds simultaneously consider increasing the size of pool with the poolSize attribute. <a-entity sound=​"src:​ #sound" autoplay=​"false">​​'
```

It seems to be calling for every frame/couple of frames. Any ideas for how to stop this? This seems to be bad behavior especially for mobile.

For reference, here's the scene code:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;';>
       <a-assets>
            <audio id="sound" src="audio.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
        </a-assets>
        <a-marker preset="custom" type="pattern" url="img/pattern-marker.patt">
        <!--<a-marker preset="hiro">-->
        <!--<a-torus-knot color="#000000" arc="180" p="2" q="7" radius="5" radius-tubular="0.1"></a-torus-knot>-->
                <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='color: black;' soundhandler> 
                </a-box>
        </a-marker>
        <a-entity sound="src: #sound" autoplay="false"></a-entity>
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

and the code that registers the component and event:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('soundhandler', {
    tick: function () {
           var entity = document.querySelector('[sound]');
         if (document.querySelector('a-marker').object3D.visible == true) {
            entity.components.sound.playSound();
        } else {
        }

     }
});
```

Comment: I'd add an "isPlayed" flag to entity.components.sound - set it to true and don't play it again once it's played.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are going for:

1) You can check if the HTML media element is playing by checking the `currentTime` property before playing the sound. Or set up any boolean variable reacting for the `playing` and `ended` Audio element events.

2) you can `pause()` the audio whenever the marker is not visible.

You can check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oqh1988t/1/), where the audio will play only if it's ended / reloaded.
More on media [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag variable and subscribe to sound events:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('soundhandler', {
    playingSound = false, //flag vble.
    soundToHandle = document.querySelector('[sound]'),
    init: function() {
      soundToHandle.stopSound = function() {  //sound stoped event
        playingSound = false;
      };
      soundToHandle.playSound = function() { //sound played event
        playingSound = true;
      };
    },
    tick: function () {
         if ((document.querySelector('a-marker').object3D.visible == true) && (!playingSound)) {
            soundToHandle.components.sound.playSound();
        } else if ((document.querySelector('a-marker').object3D.visible == false) && (playingSound)){
             soundToHandle.components.sound.stopSound();
        }

     }
});
```